# Smoke the SmokeDetector

Tags: javascript, stackexchange, chat, userscript

In [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), our spam detector is a bot named SmokeDetector.

While you can ignore the bot, you can't ignore specific replies to Smokey without ignoring users, so I wrote a UserScript to hide SmokeDetector messages and replies/calls to it by other users.

[Click Here](https://github.com/The-Quill/SmokeTheSmokeDetector/raw/master/SmokeTheSmokeDetector.user.js) to install. It's also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/The-Quill/SmokeTheSmokeDetector) and [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6844/smoke-the-smokedetector).

I used the `startsWith` and `includes` polyfills, because I was too lazy to use `indexOf`.

I tried to get as much duplicate logic out of it as possible, hence the `innerText` function, but it just feels icky at points. I'm not particularly sure how to improve it beyond extracting logic out of the main function a bit more.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name SmokeTheSmokeDetector
// @description No more smokey spam
// @version 0.0.1
// @match *://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @match *://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*
// @match *://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @author The-Quill
// @downloadURL  https://github.com/The-Quill/SmokeTheSmokeDetector/raw/master/SmokeTheSmokeDetector.user.js
// @updateURL https://github.com/The-Quill/SmokeTheSmokeDetector/raw/master/SmokeTheSmokeDetector.user.js
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
        position = position || 0;
        return this.substr(position || 0, searchString.length) === searchString;
    };
}
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
    String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
        'use strict';
        if (typeof start !== 'number') {
            start = 0;
        }
        if (start + search.length > this.length) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
    };
}
var SmokeyIdsBasedOnSite = {
    "chat.meta.stackexchange.com": 266345,
    "chat.stackexchange.com": 120914,
    "chat.stackoverflow.com": 3735529
};
var SmokeyUserId = SmokeyIdsBasedOnSite[document.location.host];
function innerText(element, selector){
    if (!selector) return "";
    var foundElement = element.querySelector(selector);
    if (!foundElement || !foundElement.innerText) return "";
    return foundElement.innerText;
}
function hideSmokeyMessage(message){
    var messageBlock = message.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (messageBlock.classList.contains('user-' + SmokeyUserId)){
        var text = innerText(message, '.content');
        if (!text.includes('fault.') && !text.includes('privileged user')){
            var parentNode = message.parentNode;
            parentNode.removeChild(message);
            if (parentNode.children.length === 0){
                messageBlock.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    var messageText = innerText(message, '.content');
    var isSmokeyResponse = innerText(message, '.mention') === '@SmokeDetector';
    if (messageText.startsWith('sd') || (messageText.startsWith('!!/') && messageText !== '!!/blame' && messageText !== '!!/amiprivileged') || isSmokeyResponse){
        var parentNode = message.parentNode;
        parentNode.removeChild(message);
        if (parentNode.children.length === 0){
            messageBlock.style.display = "none";
        }
        return;
    }
}
function nodeInsertionListener(){
    var messages = document.querySelectorAll(".monologue .message");
    Array.prototype.slice.apply(messages).forEach(hideSmokeyMessage);
}
window.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", nodeInsertionListener);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but my review is going to be short; your code looks pretty good.

---

### Refactor node deletion

You did a very good job of refactoring your code for the most part. The only repetition that I can find is here:

> ```
> var parentNode = message.parentNode;
> parentNode.removeChild(message);
> if (parentNode.children.length === 0){
>     messageBlock.style.display = "none";
> }
> ```

Perhaps it would be best to split this off into a `deleteMessage` function to keep things simple.

---

### Refactoring message content checking

This conditional is fairly lengthy:

> ```
> if (messageText.startsWith('sd') || (messageText.startsWith('!!/') && messageText !== '!!/blame' && messageText !== '!!/amiprivileged') || isSmokeyResponse)
> ```

Perhaps it would be cleaner to split this off into a separate function called `isSDCommand`.

---

### Variable confusion

In the first part of `hideSmokeyMessage`, you have this:

> ```
> var text = innerText(message, '.content');
> ```

In the second part, after the conditional, you have this:

> ```
> var messageText = innerText(message, '.content');
> ```

Two variables, same exact content but with different names and in different scopes. That's a little confusing.

You should define the `text` variable above the first conditional so both parts of the function can use it, since they both need to use it anyway.

---

### Simplifying argument checking

This is your `innerText` function:

> ```
> function innerText(element, selector){
>     if (!selector) return "";
>     var foundElement = element.querySelector(selector);
>     if (!foundElement || !foundElement.innerText) return "";
>     return foundElement.innerText;
> }
> ```

First off, if you are going to check for the existence of `selector`, why not also check for the existence of `element`? I personally think you could just drop the checking all together because

- This isn't some standard function that you are reinventing
- You always provide the second parameter

Another simplification you can make is removing the second part of the remaining conditional (the part after the `||`). If there is no text, it's going to be `""` anyway.

Now your function looks like this:

```
function innerText(element, selector){
    var foundElement = element.querySelector(selector);
    if (!foundElement) return "";
    return foundElement.innerText;
}
```

This can be even further simplified with a ternary operator now:

```
return foundElement ? foundElement.innerText : "";
```

---

### Nitpick

You can merge the `SmokeyIdsBasedOnSite` map and the `SmokeyUserId` together to make it a bit cleaner in that section:

```
var SmokeyUserId = ({
    "chat.meta.stackexchange.com": 266345,
    "chat.stackexchange.com": 120914,
    "chat.stackoverflow.com": 3735529
})[document.location.host];
```